# Actual Definition of the term: Hopf Band?

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory, geometric-topology

Sorry if this is too trivial:

I need an actual working definition of the term: **Hopf band**. I see references to it

in many searches, but never an actual precise definition. All I know so far is that it

is a Seifert surface for the Hopf link ( the disjoint union of two unknots $S^1$) , but this obviously

does not narrow things enough to an actual definition, since there is more than one

Seifert surface for every unknot. I've spent around an hour looking for a precise working
 definition.

How do people actually find these definitions?

Thanks.

EDIT: I found a "definition" ( a picture, aka, 1000 words ) in page 135 of:
http://books.google.com/books?id=mbXi8kC7DIMC&pg=PA134&dq=hopf+band&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GydsU8YR6sewBPOpgYgG&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=hopf%20band&f=false

I did not know one could do a search over all books. I'll try to remember that.

Comment: It's a band with a full $2\pi$ twist in it.

Comment: @Grumpy Parsnip .Thanks; a meta-question: how does one find a precise definitions for these terms? I searched for this for around one hour. And I've had similar problems finding precise technical definitions.

Comment: I think girls call it a "skipping rope".

Comment: @Pedro, Grumpy: Thanks; I found the answer in Google books; I did not know one could search for the term over all books. It is here: http://books.google.com/books?id=mbXi8kC7DIMC&pg=PA134&dq=hopf+band&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GydsU8YR6sewBPOpgYgG&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=hopf%20band&f=false

Comment: By band, I assume this is a twisted 2-handle, right?

Comment: @user99680 I was making a joke with the German word "hopfe/hopf". Sorry.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: don't worry, I'm embarrassed enough to be asking for a simple definition; it seems like a sort-of joke question.

Comment: @user99680 My joke was not in that spirit at all! Seems like a good question to me.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. As for your meta-question, sites such as this one are a great resource.